# Weird clipping after applying mirror modifier and merging vertices

Tags: mesh

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MVZNXL4hxZHGoRhc0QlMnFVmv6hdBeQL/view?usp=sharing

After applying a mirror modifier & merging the vertices, this faint line shows.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I could fix it?

Comment: maybe you have an edge floating, go in Edit mode and check

Comment: No, there's no edge floating

Comment: ok but it's actually pretty hard to guess what's happening from the picture you show, maybe share your file, or show a little bit more

Comment: I added a video, hope it helps

Comment: it looks like it's just the outline of your selection, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know how why it worked. But I deleted the face created by the vertices also creating the weird line, then it disappeared. Thanks for taking the time to try and help me though! Also something to note, although the vertices were in a loop, I wasn't able to select them using option-click, and now I'm able to.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by the same thing causing you to not be able to select the loop of vertices. Delete the face created by the vertices.